# Best Approach using Volley Android to Insert SQLITE Database?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-sqlite, android-volley

I'm using Volley in my android application but I'm facing a problem, I have to use volley only for async connections?

Because per example I have an 1800 record database from web service to my application I start my volley and retrieve fine but I'm inserting this records on my SQLite and when I do that my application freezy why?

I thinking volley have async methods to handle this but it freezy when I loop on a volley and insert. My dialogue stops animation and everything.

Before volley I use the Assyntask from android and never freezy my application and I'm using httpost but now I change to volley and I'm facing this issue I will share my code :

```
  public void volleyJsonObjectRequest(String url) {

        String  REQUEST_TAG = "com.androidtutorialpoint.volleyJsonObjectRequest";
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Sincronizando pedidos..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        // prepare the Request
        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // display response

                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());

                        List<HashMap<String,String>> listObjectsServer = new ArrayList<>();

                        try {

                            MDAutomap controller;
                            controller = new MDAutomap(getActivity());


                            JSONArray jsonArrayPedidos = response.getJSONArray("pedidos");
                            if (jsonArrayPedidos != null && jsonArrayPedidos.length() > 0) {

                                HashMap<String, String> pedidos = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayPedidos.length(); i++) {

                                  JSONObject obj = jsonArrayPedidos.getJSONObject(i);

                                  pedidos.put("nomeusuario", obj.getString("nomeUsuario"));
                                  pedidos.put("id", obj.getString("id"));
                                  pedidos.put("nome", obj.getString("nome"));
                                  pedidos.put("eventoid", obj.getString("eventoid"));
                                  pedidos.put("descricao", obj.getString("descricao"));
                                  pedidos.put("valor", obj.getString("valor"));
                                  pedidos.put("veiculo", obj.getString("veiculo"));
                                  pedidos.put("transactioncode", obj.getString("transactioncode"));
                                  pedidos.put("referencecode", obj.getString("referencecode"));
                                  pedidos.put("status", obj.getString("status"));
                                  pedidos.put("flag", obj.getString("flag"));
                                  pedidos.put("usuario", obj.getString("usuario"));
                                  pedidos.put("created_at", obj.getString("created_at"));
                                  pedidos.put("updated_at", obj.getString("updated_at"));

                                    if (controller.checkPedido(pedidos.get("id"))) {

                                        controller.updatePedido(pedidos);

                                    }else {

                                        controller.inserirPedido(pedidos);

                                    }


                                }

                                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                                //userMsg("Sincronizado com sucesso os pedidos.");

                            }else {

                                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }


                                //userMsg("Não existe pedidos para sincronizar.");

                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        userMsg("Não foi possível fazer conexão, por favor tenta novamente.");
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: show the code of `updatePedido` and `inserirPedido`

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it will freeze because it is getting huge data from service and inserting in Db on main UI thread . So i solved that problem by taking a async task inside volley response and it worked in my case**

```
private void hitApiForSyncDropdownsData(final String ApiType) {
    showDialog();
String jsonAsParamstr = makeJsonStr(ApiType);
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(wholeUrl, makeJsonFromStrJson(jsonAsParamstr),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    if (response.getString(Constant.Utils.responseCode).equals("1")) {
                        new ProcessJsonAsync(ApiType).execute(response, null, null);
 //processing response in Async as getting heavy reponse and inserting into DB
                    } else {
                        showShortToast(response.getString(Constant.Utils.responseMessage));
                        dismissDialog();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dismissDialog();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        showmsgForVolleyIfConnProb(error, context);
    }
});
req = setretryPolicy(req);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

**and that async Code would look like**

```
private class ProcessJsonAsync extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Integer> {
        String ApiType;

        ProcessJsonAsync(String ApiType) {
            this.ApiType = ApiType;
        }

      protected Integer doInBackground(JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
        ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer insertedResult = -1;
        try {
            JSONObject response = jsonObjects[0];
            if (response.getString(Constant.Utils.responseCode).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                JSONArray jsonarray = response.getJSONArray(Constant.Utils.responseObject);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    dataModelArraylist.add(new DataModel(jsonObj.getString("data1"), jsonObj.getString("data2"));
                }

                DataStrucTable dataStrucTable=new DataStructTable();
                insertedResult=dataStrucTable.insertArrayInDb(dataModelArraylist);
    //here it will insert thousands of entries in DB on background thread and will not hang your UI

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return insertedResult;
    }
      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        Toast.makeText(context, integer == -1 ? "Data couldn't insert in DB" :"Data successfully inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Really nice, i'm thinking about that but i read alot that volley is async that i'm thinking it was my problem or something, but it is a good aproach async inside volley?

Comment: @Wavrik ,please up a vote for me if it solves your problem, Thank you